# ERROR 000539: Error running expression_NameError: name 'shape title' is not defined

Tags: arcpy, python-2.7, error-000539

I'm trying to get the title of the shapefiles or feature classes that are in a workspace (folder or GDB), into the field as a Name in python. I know this is easier in modelbuilder by adding %Name% in field calculator. But what I'm after is to crack it in python since it gives more option to handle it further. Here's the script:

```
InWS = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
Wildcard = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
Feature_Type = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
arcpy.env.workspace = InWS
lists=arcpy.arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(Wildcard,Feature_Type)
for FC in lists:
    arcpy.AddField_management(FC, "Name", "TEXT", "", "", "100", "", "NULLABLE", "NON_REQUIRED", "")
    arcpy.CalculateField_management(FC, "Name", FC, "PYTHON", "")
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is all in one line:

```
lists=arcpy.arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(Wildcard,Feature_Type)
```

should be:

```
lists=arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(Wildcard,Feature_Type)
```

or for quick testing try this first - just in case your variables are not being set properly yet

```
lists=arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
```